# Communicating between android studio and unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am developing an AR app. I am developing all the UI and menus in android studio and a scene in unity. I am trying to pass a string from my android studio project to my unity scene. Is there a built-in way to do this? I am trying to implement it with writing to files but it doesn't seem like a good way to do it.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many different ways:

- Display your `mUnityPlayer` within a Fragment and then handle the scene with the `FragmentManager`
- Extend an Activity from `UnityPlayerActivity` and communicate as the rest of activities
- Use `SharedPreferences` and its listeners

You can think of many other ways to tackle this issue, hope any of them give you a hint

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How exactly would I receive the string within my unity code?

Comment: As I have suggested, it will depend on how you are implementing the Unity view/activity

Answer (score 0):

Get classes.jar from one of the sub-folders from

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono
```

or

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp
```

depending on if you are using mono or IL2CPP as Scripting Backend to build your Android Project.

Once you import the classes.jar module into your Android Java project, you can the use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` to call C# function from Java.

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Gameobject Name","Method","Message")
```

If you plan to extend *UnityPlayerActivity* then grab *UnityPlayerActivity.java* from

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Source\com\unity3d\player.
```

Finally, `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` is what you are looking for. There are many tutorials out there on how to use it, if you are still confused.